# jQuery Cookies Plugin doesn't save cookies

Tags: jquery, cookies

Hi i try to do this with the cookies plugin in jquery

```
$.cookie('XXX', 'the_value', 22);
alert($.cookie('XXX'));
```

But the alert output null (i tried this in local)

Why?

Plugin is there: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/

Comment: What is the `22` doing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the expiration:

```
$.cookie('XXX', 'the_value', { expires: 22 });
```

[Read this article](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/):

```
$.cookie("example", "foo");
```

> This is a session cookie which is set for the current path level and will be destroyed when the user exits the browser. To make the same cookie last for e.g. 7 days do this:

```
$.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 7 });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am pretty sure is this I will try this tomorrow;)

Comment: I still got null with this code :/
Even just this " $.cookie("example", "foo");
 alert($.cookie('example'));" is null

Comment: i just found it i needed to run it on a local server if you just launch the html file directly in your browser the cookies don't work, i didn't know this ;)